# flutter remove back button on appbar

Tags: flutter, navigation, back-button, appbar

I am wondering, if anyone knows of a way to remove the back button that shows up on the `appBar` in a flutter app when you use `Navigator.pushNamed` to go to another page. The reason I do not want it on this resulting page is that it is coming from the navigation and I want users to use the `logout` button instead, so that the session starts over.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You can remove the back button by passing an empty `new Container()` as the [`leading`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/leading.html) argument to your [`AppBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html).

If you find yourself doing this, you probably don't want the user to be able to press the device's back button to get back to the earlier route. Instead of calling `pushNamed`, try calling [`Navigator.pushReplacementNamed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacementNamed.html) to cause the earlier route to disappear.

The function `pushReplacementNamed` will remove the previous route in the  backstack and replace it with the new route.

Full code sample for the latter is below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LogoutPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Logout Page"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text('You have been logged out'),
      ),
    );
  }

}
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Remove Back Button"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.fullscreen_exit),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/logout");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
      routes: {
        "/logout": (_) => new LogoutPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Collin, pushReplacementNamed doesn't seem to remove the possibility of going back with the system back arrow.

Comment: @Collin Jackson, Does `pushReplacementNamed()` dispose previous screen widget (and all depending data & states)?

Comment: @Jackpap that's because it really shows the arrow if there is a previous route. If it's the only route, then there's nothing to go back to. In your case, use the empty Container() method.

Comment: The empty container method seems to result in a space where the back button would have been so the Appbar title is moved across slightly. Still not an ideal method.

Comment: appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("App Bar without Back Button"),
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
),

As shown below is the correct method I guess.

Comment: This does get rid of the back button on the app bar but it would still occupy space there if you have center title set to true, and hence you won't have the title in center of appbar, so a better approach would be to use ```automaticallyImplyLeading: false```

Answer (score 631):

I believe the solutions are the following

You actually either:

- Don't want to display that ugly back button ( :] ), and thus go for :
  `AppBar(...,automaticallyImplyLeading: false,...)`;
- Don't want the user to go back - **replacing current view** - and thus go for:
  `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(## your routename here ##)`;
- Don't want the user to go back - **replacing a certain view back in the stack** - and thus use:
  `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(## your routename here ##, f(Route<dynamic>)→bool);`
  where f is a function returning `true`when meeting the last view you want to keep in the stack (right before the new one);
- Don't want the user to go back - **EVER** - emptying completely the navigator stack with:
  `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, ## your routename here ##, (_) => false);`

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! pushReplacementNamed() wasn't working for me, but the user going back EVER is what ended up working! Thank you!

Comment: indeed this is the best answer.

Comment: Thank you, I had to use "pushReplacementNamed" instead of "popAndPushNamed"

Comment: `automaticallyImplyLeading: false` is the answer i'm looking for..

Comment: Thanks  with getx  ``Navigator.of(Get.context!)
            .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);`` worked

Answer (score 334):

A simple way to remove the back button in the AppBar is to set `automaticallyImplyLeading` to `false`.

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("App Bar without Back Button"),
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
),
```

Comment: While this is simple to implement, for the given scenario, `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` is the correct solution. What you suggest is a workaround that if applied in all scenarios, may eventually infer wrong behavior, like somewhere that someone would like that the `AppBar` continues to imply the leading behavior (i.e.: back navigation button)

Comment: Although it removes the back arrow icon but still you can go back by pressing back button of device

Comment: What is the best way to remove the back button on Android only, so that an Android user must use the device's back button to go back, but an iOS user sees an AppBar back button?

Answer (score 69):

**automaticallyImplyLeading:**

This checks whether we want to apply the back widget(leading widget) over the app bar or not.
If the automaticallyImplyLeading is false then automatically space is given to the title and if If the leading widget is true, then this parameter has no effect.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // Used for removing back buttoon. 
          title: new Center(
            child: new Text("Demo App"),
          ),
        ),
        body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: Text("Hello world!"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: now i understand the back widget is called leading widget, before i confuse why its called ImplyLeading

Answer (score 22):

just use automaticallyImplyLeading in AppBar()

```
appBar: AppBaar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
)
```

Answer (score 15):

**Use this for slivers AppBar**

```
SliverAppBar (
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 0,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        pinned: true,
      ),
```

**Use this for normal Appbar**

```
 appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text
    ("You decide on the appbar name"
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,), 
    elevation: 0,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,

),
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to hide back button use below code

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Remove Back Button'),
    
    //hide back button
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
   ),
  body: Center(
    child: Container(),
  ),
);
}
}
```

If you want to hide back button and stop the pop action use below code

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new WillPopScope(

  onWillPop: () async => false,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Second Screen"),
      //For hide back button
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    ),
    body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Back'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        )
    ),
  ),
);
 }
```

[image: []

Answer (score 8):

The AppBar widget has a property called `automaticallyImplyLeading`. By default it's value is `true`. If you don't want flutter automatically build the back button for you then just make the property `false`.

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("YOUR_APPBAR_TITLE"), 
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
),
```

To add your custom back button

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("YOUR_APPBAR_TITLE"), 
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  leading: YOUR_CUSTOM_WIDGET(),
),
```

Answer (score 7):

If navigating to another page .                                              `Navigator.pushReplacement()` can be used. It can be used If you're navigating from login to home screen.        Or you can use .
 `AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading: false)`

Answer (score 4):

SliverAppBar(
automaticallyImplyLeading: false,}

Answer (score 3):

in your appBar,  put  `automaticallyImplyLeading` in false :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Navigator.pushNamed` the back-arrow appears automatically on the new screen's appBar for going back to the previous screen. If you don't want this functionality all you have to do is write `automaticallyImplyLeading: false` in your appBar properties.

Answer (score 1):

Just Make it transparent, and no action while pressend

```
AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

it is easy find the button in main.dart or any place as I set in main.dart

change this

Navigator.push(

to

> ```
>   Navigator.pushReplacement(
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`AppBar` widget automatically includes a `back button` when the current screen has been pushed onto the navigation stack. If you want to remove this back button, you have a few options depending on your needs and the structure of your app.

**Option 1: Use automaticallyImplyLeading Property**

```
AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  // Other AppBar properties
)
```

**Option 2: Custom Leading Widget**

```
AppBar(
  leading: Container(), // Effectively removes the back button, but can be any widget.
  // Other AppBar properties
)
```

**Option 3: Modifying the Navigation Logic**

For example, using `Navigator.pushReplacement` or `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil` to navigate to a new page won't add a back button because the previous page is removed from the stack.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewPage()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove space as well set `titleSpacing:0` .

```
 appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("How do you rate us?"),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        titleSpacing: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.close))
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

in flutter  >= 3.10
set  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in the appbar:

```
automaticallyImplyLeading: false
```

Make this `true` so you will get back button.

Answer (score -1):

```
  appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("SmartDocs SPAY"),backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent, automaticallyImplyLeading:false,
        leading: new Container(),
      ),
```

It is working Fine

Comment: we need to provide the leading : new Container() tag