# Flutter - Pass values between routes using pushReplacementNamed

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to pass values between routes using `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed()`, but I'm not getting it.

I can not figure out what the correct syntax and logic is in which data will exit `pushReplacementNamed` and get the `routes` key.

Can you help me?

Enter the code below to facilitate understanding:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/form': (BuildContext context) => new FormPage(email: ???, header: {'auth': ???}),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/form', {email: 'myemail@flutter.com', header: {'auth': '1234'}});
        },
        child: new Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FormPage({Key key, this.email, this.header}) : super(key: key);
  String email;
  Map header;
  @override
  FormPageState createState() => new FormPageState();
}

class FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(widget.email),
          new Text(widget.header['auth'])
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**After correction:**

The purpose of trying to use `pushReplacementNamed` was to remove the route history, so if the user presses the device's back button to get back to the earlier route, the route would no longer exist. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978216/flutter-remove-back-button-on-appbar)

The reason for this implementation is to be used on a login page, if the user has already been authenticated by `google sign` he is redirected to the next page passing login parameters and could not return to the login page by device's back button.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/form': (BuildContext context) => new FormPage(), //new
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(                                                         //new
            new MaterialPageRoute(                                                                       //new
              settings: const RouteSettings(name: '/form'),                                              //new
              builder: (context) => new FormPage(email: 'myemail@flutter.com', header: {'auth': '1234'}) //new
            )                                                                                            //new
          );                                                                                             //new
        },
        child: new Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FormPage({Key key, this.email, this.header}) : super(key: key);
  String email;
  Map header;
  @override
  FormPageState createState() => new FormPageState();
}

class FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(widget.email),
          new Text(widget.header['auth'])
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you might be miss understanding how result works. The result goes back to the previous widget that pushed the last route and is using `await` for the result of the `Future` sent back by the previous call to `push`. Do you simply want to start a route with parameters? Then you can do this.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
  new MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: const RouteSettings(name: '/form'),
    builder: (context) => new FormPage(
      email: 'myemail@flutter.com',
      header: {'auth': '1234'},
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 8):

1. You can use  `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/route', arguments: 'Test String');` to pass any object as arguments from first widget.
2. And use `String s = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;` to parse the arguments after `initState()` method, like `didChangeDependencies()` or `build(BuildContext context)` in the second widget.

Eg:

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
 RouteSettings settings = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings;
 if (settings.arguments != null) {
  CustomObject obj = settings.arguments as CustomObject;
 }
 super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

3. Instead of Step 2.
   You can also initialize the widget class with those arguments by using `onGenerateRoute: (settings) {}` in your `App` Widget.
   Eg:

   ```
   class App extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
       /*...*/
        routes: {
          /*Don't add those routes with arguments here..*/
        },
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if (settings.name == SECOND_SCREEN_ROUTE) {
            if (settings.arguments != null) {
              CustomObject obj = settings.arguments as CustomObject;
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return SecondScreen(obj);
                },
              );
           }
          }
          assert(false, 'Need to implement ${settings.name}');
          return null;
         });
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: how can we pass multiple arguments? Can we pass multiple arguments in `Map<String, dynamic>` format? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: I am passing multiple parameters in `Map<String, dynmic>` format instead of `String` because I have to pass multiple params. But getting error like `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Kamlesh make sure you are parsing arguments in didChangeDependencies() or build(BuildContext context)

Comment: Kindly update your answer and pass 2 params and also show how can we get/use params in `didChangeDependencies()`. Look forward to hear you. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh updated my answer with some examples. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge. I have passed 2 parameters at the time of pushreplacementnamed navigation. I can get them `settings.arguments` in `onGenerateRoute:`. I am passing those 2 params in `Map` type on `SecondScreen`. I can use them as widget.param1, widget.param2 but when I use `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings` in `didChangeDependencies()`, it does not work for me and giving me error like Null cannot be Map. Could you please sugggest me what is the issue and why am I not able to use `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings` in `didChangeDependencies()`?