# Flutter Navigator not working as expected

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-routes

So I want a user to be able to go back to the '/' named route after he/she reaches upto a certain page. The condition is that when that page is reached, user should be routed to '/' only on Navigator.pop(context).

ie., Lets say I have routes configured such that :

**User is at '/' > Clicks a button and pushNamed to '/abc' > Clicks a button and pushNamed to '/xyz' > Clicks a button and pushNamed to '/mnq'**

Now, I want that when user is at /mnq and Navigator.pop(context) is executed, user should be sent back to '/' and not anywhere else.

When I'm at /xyz, I tried to do a Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/mnq', ModalRoute.withName('/'), arguments:....) but It does not work because when Navigator.pop is executed after reaching /mnq, I see a black screen.

Is there a way to do this. Please note that I need to send arguments from /xyz to /mnq.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `pushReplacementNamed()`

`'/'` pushNamed to `'/abc'` pushReplacementNamed to `'/xyz'` pushReplacementNamed to `'/mnq`'

read this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31) for more information

Answer (score 0):

pushNamedAndRemoveUntil is remove all page before. when you use back/pop, it will show black because no page before. you can pass argument with pushReplacementNamed [Flutter - Pass values between routes using pushReplacementNamed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088715/flutter-pass-values-between-routes-using-pushreplacementnamed) or store data in local https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 0):

1st. on pressing a button to user should be sent back to '/'

simply use `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));`

in place of `Navigator.pop(context);`

2nd.  if user tab back button

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
        return false;
      },
 child: Scaffold(......),
)
```