# How I can show back button when device is iPhone

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, dart-2

I am developing an app using flutter. But I am stuck on a situation that Android device has its default back button but iPhone don't. So I need to show back button when I open app in iOS device. 
Also if there is any other built in functionality available please guide me.

Comment: if you're not using material and you're building your own custom interface, you'll need 'dart:io' [Platform.isIOS](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/Platform/isIOS.html) to detect iOS...

Answer (score 0):

By default, we will *get the backButton* for **both** the android and iOS. If we don't want it, we can remove by giving empty container(`Container()`) to the `leading` value to the appBar. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978216/flutter-remove-back-button-on-appbar) for more details

Comment: Dinesh actually I am not using AppBar in container.

Comment: Can u show your code/page where you are not using appBar

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Scaffold` with `AppBar`, it automatically creates the virtual back button at the top-right of the screen.  (Assuming you `push` the Widget from another screen).

```
     return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Title"),
            ),
            body: YourBody(),

            );
```