# How to remove or hide back icon from AppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I need to hide or remove back button or back icon from AppBar is that possible? 
If it is possible then how?
I set   `leading: null,` but it is still there without any changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter remove back button on appbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978216/flutter-remove-back-button-on-appbar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the following line to your `AppBar` should work:

```dart
automaticallyImplyLeading: false
```