# Back button linked to previous Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, button, mobile

I want to know how can I link a page to previous, instead of choosing an only path, because sometimes there is other paths to the same page.

```
 Navigator.pop(context);
```

Haven't worked for me, I only get a black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the way how you opened the page;

open new screen:

```
// Within the First Page widget

  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
  );
```

now you can return to the first page using Navigator.pop()
like that :

```
// Within the Second Page widget

  Navigator.pop(context);
```

Comment: You are very right, thank you. The only issue is that it adds a back button on the back screen where it didn't have any button before.

Comment: you can customize the app bar as you want , You can remove the back button by passing an empty new Container() as the leading argument to your AppBar. check this out it has answer of your issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978216/flutter-remove-back-button-on-appbar

Comment: Thank you again, you're a great help