# How to remove Android back buttons on MaterialApp on Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
  OrientationSingleton.left = true;
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft])
      .then((_) {
    runApp(new MyApp());
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
```

Here's my app. I've found some tutorials on how to remove it: [flutter remove back button on appbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978216/flutter-remove-back-button-on-appbar) but it's for an AppBar. I tried making my app work on an `AppBar` but I get

```
MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
```

Because I rely on `MediaQuery.of()` inside my app.

So, how do I remove the Android back, home and square buttons on Flutter for a `MaterialApp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error message, `SystemChrome` requires `context` -  a place to call it could be the `initState()` method of the `Widget`:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
     OrientationSingleton.left = true;
     SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(); // your MaterialApp class
   }
}
```

To *hide* the system bottom bar on Android, one option could be to call the `setEnabledSystemUIOverlays()` function with an empty list:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

However, this function is not globally supported on all Android devices.

Comment: Doing these things in initState() did not work but doing them all on main() like I did worked. Also `super.initState();` wasn't possible.

Comment: I've edited the code to support a `Stateful` widget, which is required to use the `initState()` function