# Flutter, How to remove the back button in navigation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code in my Homepage.dart after the login, I wonder if i can remove the backbutton in the navigation bar, please see the picture below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Flutter App'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: 0, // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.mail),
            title: new Text('Messages'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text('Profile')
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is how i call the Homepage

```
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage()));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) before asking on SO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Instead of calling `Push` try `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(newRouteName, (route) => false)` This will remove the previous route with new one.

And a simple way to remove the back button

`appBar: AppBar( title: Text("App Bar without Back Button"), automaticallyImplyLeading: false, ),`

Comment: What if we want to disable the back navigation on a specific screen?

Comment: Yes,  you can see here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46713257/7422077